# Render multiple relationships via a single list

Tags: page-layout, related-list, lookup-field

I use salesforce to schedule appointments for psychology research studies. The appointments for the studies I'm scheduling each have 2 participants (renamed account object). Currently, I have two lookup fields on the "appointment" object, but this means that each participant/account has to have two related lists to show their appointments (Appointments as Participant 1 and Appointments as Participant 2, see photo).

[image]

My main goal is to get this set up so there is only one related list: "Appointments" that will show on *both* participant's pages. Do I need to make a junction object or some sort of multi-select lookup to do this?? I tried making a junction object called "dyads" but this got quite complicated and didn't solve my issue.

Thank! Please let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: Junction object would be a start, yes: [example](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/build-a-data-model-for-a-recruiting-app/junction-object-job-postings). If this is too much, look into Salesforce Scheduler product.